# Enable Button on Textbox/combobox/RadDatePicker Change using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

In an asp.net form, I have some textboxes, Comboboxes, RadDatepickers,RadComboBoxes textbox and an update button. I want that whenever the user makes a change in any of the fields, the button will be enabled.

To solve this issue, I assigned a css calss to each of them:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtRequestedQuantityTo" runat="server" CssClass="UpdateCSS"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:DropDownList ID="CmbFuelType" runat="server" CssClass="UpdateCSS"></asp:DropDownList>
<telerik:RadDatePicker ID="DatDeliveryDateETS" Runat="server" CssClass="UpdateCSS"> </telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

and used below javascript code :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#BtnUpdate").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    $("input.UpdateCSS").keyup(function () {
        $("#BtnUpdate").removeAttr('disabled');
    });

    $("input.UpdateCSS").change(function () {
        $("#BtnUpdate").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
```

it's working fine with textbox but not with combobox and RadDatePicker.

Comment: Not sure but check the qoutes.for textbox you are using single quotes

Comment: try use with id's.And be aware that telerik:RadDatePicker creates divs and it may set the id to that divs

Comment: Have you tried removing the `input.` from `$("input.UpdateCSS").change(function () {`

Comment: @shreesha, Im not seeing any difference between any of them .

Comment: @Suren , I'm looking for an easier way as I have too many fields in one form

Comment: Kieran, I tried your suggestion but no difference. Thank you. Any other suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

asp controls will not render the element with the same `ID` as you're expecting..

you'll have to use `$("#<%= BtnUpdate.ClientID %>")`

OR

you can set `ClientIDMode="Static"` within each asp control to prevent the `ID` from changing

Comment: Thank you godmode, I tried your suggestion but no change. my code is working fine with textboxes but not with combobox and raddatepicker. Maybe nstead of change and keyup I need to check something else?